# USB Ethernet Adapter is Losing Assigned IP Address

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am trying to configure an USB Ethernet Adapter on my Ubuntu 22.04

```
user@host:~# ifconfig
enx806d970abd77: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::21fc:1eee:94e6:2a14  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 80:6d:97:0a:bd:77  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 108  bytes 18012 (18.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 772  bytes 133175 (133.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I am able to configure an IPv4 address to the interface by executing the following command:

```
user@host:~# ip address add 11.1.1.1/24 dev enx806d970abd77
user@host:~# ifconfig
enx806d970abd77: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 11.1.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 80:6d:97:0a:bd:77  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 108  bytes 18012 (18.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 858  bytes 147673 (147.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But I am losing the configured IP Address after sometime (2-3 minutes)

```
# after sometime
user@host:~# ifconfig
enx806d970abd77: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::21fc:1eee:94e6:2a14  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 80:6d:97:0a:bd:77  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 108  bytes 18012 (18.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 772  bytes 133175 (133.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```